# MongoDB Binary data type in Apache Drill

Tags: mongodb, apache-drill

I am very new to Apache Drill as well as mongoDB In my mongoDB collection there are several fields which has been stored as Binary data type whenever I am trying to access those fields I am getting this error `INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: Failure while reading document. - Parser was at record: 1 Fragment: 0:0`

Please note I am able to access other fields in Apache Drill

This is the log details

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Failure while reading ExtendedJSON typed value. Expected a VALUE_STRING but received a token of type START_OBJECT
 at [Source: (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.SeekableBAIS); line: 1, column: 22]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkToken(VectorOutput.java:188)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkNextToken(VectorOutput.java:151)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkNextToken(VectorOutput.java:143)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.innerRun(VectorOutput.java:101)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput$MapVectorOutput.run(VectorOutput.java:315)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeMapDataIfTyped(JsonReader.java:386)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDataAllText(JsonReader.java:345)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDataSwitch(JsonReader.java:190)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDocument(JsonReader.java:178)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.easy.json.reader.BaseJsonReader.writeToVector(BaseJsonReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.easy.json.reader.BaseJsonReader.write(BaseJsonReader.java:70)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.mongo.MongoRecordReader.next(MongoRecordReader.java:227)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
2023-05-11 09:01:50,051 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] ERROR o.a.d.e.physical.impl.BaseRootExec - Batch dump started: dumping last 2 failed batches
2023-05-11 09:01:50,051 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] ERROR o.a.d.exec.physical.impl.ScanBatch - ScanBatch[container=org.apache.drill.exec.record.VectorContainer@3daa59a4[recordCount = 0, schemaChanged = true, schema = null, wrappers = [], ...], currentReader=MongoRecordReader[reader=JsonReader[Line=1, Column=23, Field=_id]], schema=null]
2023-05-11 09:01:50,051 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] ERROR o.a.d.e.p.i.p.ProjectRecordBatch - ProjectRecordBatch[projector=null, hasRemainder=false, remainderIndex=0, recordCount=0, container=org.apache.drill.exec.record.VectorContainer@78a8c075[recordCount = 0, schemaChanged = true, schema = null, wrappers = [], ...]]
2023-05-11 09:01:50,052 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] ERROR o.a.d.e.physical.impl.BaseRootExec - Batch dump completed.
2023-05-11 09:01:50,052 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:0:0: State change requested RUNNING --> FAILED
2023-05-11 09:01:50,052 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] INFO  o.a.d.e.w.fragment.FragmentExecutor - 1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:0:0: State change requested FAILED --> FINISHED
2023-05-11 09:01:50,056 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] WARN  o.a.d.exec.rpc.control.WorkEventBus - Fragment 1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:0:0 manager is not found in the work bus.
2023-05-11 09:01:50,057 [qtp720948827-159] ERROR o.a.d.e.server.rest.QueryResources - Query from Web UI Failed: {}
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: INTERNAL_ERROR ERROR: Failure while reading document. - Parser was at record: 1

Fragment: 0:0

Please, refer to logs for more information.

[Error Id: 443871f6-2a18-4c43-b05a-969ecb8284d1 on ip-172-30-0-165.ap-south-1.compute.internal:31010]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.RestQueryRunner.submitQuery(RestQueryRunner.java:99)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.RestQueryRunner.run(RestQueryRunner.java:54)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.QueryResources.submitQuery(QueryResources.java:158)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor64.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:52)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:124)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:79)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:475)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:234)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1631)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.header.ResponseHeadersSettingFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersSettingFilter.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.CsrfTokenValidateFilter.doFilter(CsrfTokenValidateFilter.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.server.rest.CsrfTokenInjectFilter.doFilter(CsrfTokenInjectFilter.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1624)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1434)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1594)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:645)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:409)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:883)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1034)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.DrillRuntimeException: Failure while reading document. - Parser was at record: 1
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.mongo.MongoRecordReader.next(MongoRecordReader.java:244)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScanBatch.internalNext(ScanBatch.java:234)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScanBatch.next(ScanBatch.java:298)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:119)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:111)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.innerNext(AbstractUnaryRecordBatch.java:59)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.project.ProjectRecordBatch.innerNext(ProjectRecordBatch.java:85)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.record.AbstractRecordBatch.next(AbstractRecordBatch.java:170)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next(BaseRootExec.java:103)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.ScreenCreator$ScreenRoot.innerNext(ScreenCreator.java:81)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.physical.impl.BaseRootExec.next(BaseRootExec.java:93)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.lambda$run$0(FragmentExecutor.java:321)
    at .......(:0)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1762)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.work.fragment.FragmentExecutor.run(FragmentExecutor.java:310)
    at org.apache.drill.common.SelfCleaningRunnable.run(SelfCleaningRunnable.java:38)
    at .......(:0)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failure while reading ExtendedJSON typed value. Expected a VALUE_STRING but received a token of type START_OBJECT
 at [Source: (org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.SeekableBAIS); line: 1, column: 22]
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkToken(VectorOutput.java:188)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkNextToken(VectorOutput.java:151)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.checkNextToken(VectorOutput.java:143)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput.innerRun(VectorOutput.java:101)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.VectorOutput$MapVectorOutput.run(VectorOutput.java:315)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeMapDataIfTyped(JsonReader.java:386)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDataAllText(JsonReader.java:345)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDataSwitch(JsonReader.java:190)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.vector.complex.fn.JsonReader.writeDocument(JsonReader.java:178)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.easy.json.reader.BaseJsonReader.writeToVector(BaseJsonReader.java:99)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.easy.json.reader.BaseJsonReader.write(BaseJsonReader.java:70)
    at org.apache.drill.exec.store.mongo.MongoRecordReader.next(MongoRecordReader.java:227)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
2023-05-11 09:01:50,069 [1ba35102-3d17-c54d-95f6-a6863504647b:frag:0:0] WARN  o.a.d.e.w.f.QueryStateProcessor - Dropping request to move to COMPLETED state as query is already at FAILED state (which is terminal).
```

I try converting function which was mention in the document like `CONVERT_TO()` and `CONVERT_FROM()` although no luck

Comment: Have you tried enabling the bson reader in Drill?  There is a system option called `store.mongo.bson.record.reader`.  Maybe set that to `true` and see if that helps.